# Vue jS: input auto filled

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my Vue JS code below i have input `total price` and two inputs `paid` and `percentage`, i wanted to do an algorithm that what ever user wrote inside `paid` input an auto percentage should be filled in `percentage` input and ofc this percentage is from `total price` input, also when user write in `percentage` input the `paid` should be auto filled and so on.

Is there a way to do this in Vue js?

P.S: I wrote `v-model=instpaid` and `v-model=instprice` that posts data to API

```html
<input type="number" v-model="instPrice" class="price-input mt-3" placeholder=" total price" required />
<br />
<input type="number" v-model="instPaid" class="price-input mt-3"                                                                placeholder=" paid " required />
<input type="number"  class="price-input mt-3" placeholder=" percenatge"                                                                  required />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      instPrice: 0,
      instPaid: 0,
      pct: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    calc(pct) {
      pct === true ?
        this.instPaid = (this.instPrice / 100 * this.pct).toFixed(2)
      :
        this.pct = (this.instPaid / this.instPrice * 100).toFixed(2)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input type="number" v-model="instPrice" placeholder=" total price" required />
  <br />
  <input type="number" v-model="instPaid" placeholder=" paid" @keyup="calc(false)" required />
  <input type="number" placeholder=" percenatge" @keyup="calc(true)" v-model="pct" required />
</div>
```